# How to configure proxy in current kubernetes container?

Tags: kubernetes, proxy

I am using a kuberntes cluster. For now it works without internet connection. I want to receive alerts to my telegram from this cluster.

I configured proxy-server for internet connection. Contained is configured for this proxy. Exports are in `.bashrc` too, but when pod starts - it returns an error: connection refused. Everything is going throw main channel, not proxy.

Example of telegram-pod, which I am trying to use:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: http-telegram-notify
  namespace: telegram
spec:
  selector:
    app: http-telegram-notify
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: http-telegram-notify
  namespace: telegram
  labels:
    app: http-telegram-notify
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: http-telegram-notify
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: http-telegram-notify
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: http-telegram-notify
        image: 1flx/http-telegram-notify:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: TELEGRAM_TOKEN
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: telegram-bot-api-token
              key: token
```

How to configure pod to use proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided, you need to add these entries to configure the pods to use your proxy settings:

```
    env:
    - name: TELEGRAM_TOKEN
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: telegram-bot-api-token
          key: token

    - name: HTTP_PROXY
      value: "http://proxy-server:proxy-port"
    - name: HTTPS_PROXY
      value: "http://proxy-server:proxy-port"
    - name: NO_PROXY
      value: "localhost,127.0.0.1,cluster-domain"
```

Change "proxy-server" and "proxy-port" with the values for your proxy server. Also, make sure to replace "cluster-domain" with the domain of your Kubernetes cluster, so that internal cluster communication is not routed through the proxy. Keep in mind that setting NO_PROXY is essential to make sure that internal communication doesn't go through the proxy. Restart the pod to apply the changes and it should use the specified proxy settings when the pod starts.